# Can't connect to firebird database using Django

Tags: python, django, firebird, python-3.8

First time using Django, so I  looked up a tutorial - I followed [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) and everything went fine, until I had to adjust the settings.py file, where I followed [this other link](https://pypi.org/project/django-firebird/) and got this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'firebird' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

I have django-firebird installed via `pip install django-firebird`, I have a different python script which uses `import fdb` just fine, and I have been able to access my firebird database regularly with the *other* python script, so what could be causing this error?

ps.: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/install/#database-installation) branched out from the [first link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) mentioned as the follow-up steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last stable release of django-firebird is 1.11 which is compatible with django 1.11 LTS. This is the recommended version to use. Check the [Issue](https://github.com/maxirobaina/django-firebird/issues/100)

If you are using **Django 2.x** you need to downgrade. 
[But if you use Python 3.8 you will not be able to downgrade!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/install/#faq-python-version-support)

In this case I would recommend using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) with [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/firebird.html) to integrate with firebird

Comment: [But according to this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/install/#faq-python-version-support) I can't downgrade, since I'm using python 3.8... Is there another option?

Comment: @5Daydreams maybe the best solution is use another database, Django work's great with PostgreSQL

Comment: What I'm supposed to build has to use firebird, though... Is there something other than Django that I can use with python 3.8 that can work with firebird?

Comment: @5Daydreams If you need to use Firebird, and Django is not a requirement, i recommend to use Flask with SQLAlchemy to integrate with firebird https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/firebird.html

Comment: Alright, you should edit your answer when possible - thanks a lot!

Comment: OTOH how hard should it be to port Django DB plugin from Django 1.x API to Django 2.x API ? I do not think there was a lot of changes there, DB access APIs should more follow database realities, than Django's. Maybe one just could look how other DB plugins were upgraded to Django 2 and do the same with Firebird plugin?

Answer (score 0):

For Django 2.2.x we recommend stable/2.2.x branch with support for firebird 3 and python 3.8 , first pre release is here

https://pypi.org/project/django-firebird/2.2a1/